# Generar un for en javascript al cual le envio el tamaño por un input e imprimir cada posicion como un div

Tags: javascript, html5

Quiero enviar por medio de un `input` el tamaño de un arreglo ese tamaño se captura en JavaScript y luego se recorre con un `for`, la idea es que cada posición se imprima como un `div` con colores diferentes.

```js
var tamaño = null;
    
    
    function sub(){
      tamaño = document.getElementsByName("tamaño")[0].value;
    var text = "";
    var i;
    
    for (i = 0; i < tamaño; i++) {
        text += "The number is " + i + "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
    
    };
```

```html
<h2>Tamaño array</h2>
<form name="form" method="post" >
 <input type="text" name="tamaño"><br><br>

</form>
<button onclick="sub()">Prueba</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: **Es importante que leas [ask]**, debes agregar el código que has intentado usar para poder ayudarte. Te invito a que te hagas el [tour] para que entiendas cual es el funcionamiento básico del sitio !

Comment: ¿Jesús nos puedes mostrar lo que haz logrado hacer hasta ahora? Con código, por su puesto.

Comment: podrías mostrarnos que tanto has intentado?

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacer algo así para lograr tu objetivo, solo basta en generar un `<div>` cada vez que se ingrese al ciclo `for` y manejar de manera aleatoria los colores.

```js
function sub(){
  var tamano = document.getElementsByName("tamano")[0].value;
  var text = "";
  
  var colores = ['red', 'green', 'chocolate', 'black', 'blue'];

  for (var i = 0; i < tamano; i++) {
    var aleatorio = Math.floor(Math.random() * colores.length);
    
    document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML += '<div class="caja" style="background: '+ colores[aleatorio] +'"></div>'
  }
};
```

```css
.caja{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  background: red;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Tamaño array</h2>

<form name="form" method="post" >
  <input type="text" name="tamano"><br><br>
</form>
<button onclick="sub()">Prueba</button>

<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Comment: Gracias a todos, disculpen por la manera de preguntar, fue la primera vez

Comment: Sí la respuesta ayudo en tu solución te invito a que la marques cómo aceptada para que los futuros desarrolladores sepan que fue la solución correcta además te invito para que hagas el [tour] para que sepas el funcionamiento básico del sitio, saludos !!